# Angular 6 : Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 6 I have downloaded the ready-made angular template from [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial)

Navigated to root folder & Executed `npm install` trying to run the application `ng serve` but it's showing error

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-6-registration-login-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-6-registration-login-example.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.0.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "webpack": "4.8.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.4"
  }
}
```

My environment configuration is,

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 8.11.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.3
... common, compiler, core, forms, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          0.6.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.6.3 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.2.0
typescript                   2.8.4
webpack                      4.8.1
```

Please help me to address this issue.

Comment: execute `npm run start`

Comment: The tutorial you linked doesn't use the angular cli. `ng serve` is an angular cli command, and requires the `angular.json` file to run.

Comment: You're welcome, mate.

Comment: Since you are new to angular I would recommend you to use `Angular-CLI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your Project Does not use Angular-CLI you cannot execute `ng serve` which resulted in the error because `ng serve` looks out for this configuration file to kickstart your app

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

it uses `webpack` and all the `webpack` configuration is stored in webpack.config.js.
if you observe your package.json you could see under script section `start` and `build`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
```

you can execute these scripts using `npm`
    Execute `npm run start` for devlopment build

Answer (score 0):

If you read the package.json. `angular/cli` isn't installed, therefore run `ng serve` would not work.

The package.json file shows below commands and you should run it `npm start`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error message, I ran "npm install," my project got all of the modules and it ran.

Answer (score -1):

i have been working with angular 6 latest version but got work with a proyect with version 1.6.8, i can't run ng serve because i get error that the angular.json couldnt be found.

this is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "mktools2.0",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.2",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^1.4.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```